# 3 independent var with 2 levels

Tags: anova, sampling

1. There are 3 independent variables (carb, protein, fat) in my experiment, each with two levels (low and High). I am trying to figure out if 3-Way ANOVA would be the best method.
   Example: 
   Carb (low and high); 
   Protein (low and high)
   Fat (low and high)
2. How do I figure out the sample size of the participants in this in-between subjects experiment?
3. What is the essence of conducting a pre-test and a post-test in such an experiment? Is it really required? Is it the same as post-hoc??

Thanks

Comment: The experimental design has 2 group manipulations, A and B. Say I want to examine if two different types of diets A: (high carb, high protein, high fat) and B: (low carb, low protein, low fat)has an effect on prostate cancer. Which test is appropriate? Do we necessarily need to use 3-way ANOVA or t-tests will be proper in that kind of scenario?

Comment: By manipulating them separately, do you imply the following: carb (low and high); protein (low and high); fat (low and high)? I am curious to know the best method to apply here. Thanks

Comment: So this is what I got:                                            1 Main Effects
Ho: µhigh = µLow
Ha: Not Ho

3 Two Way Interactions:
Ho: There is no interaction between Carb and Protein
Ha: There is an interaction between Carb and Protein

Ho: There is no interaction between Carb and Fat
Ha: There is an interaction between Carb and Fat

Ho: There is no interaction between Fat and Protein
Ha: There is an interaction between Fat and Protein

1 Three-Way Interactions
Ho: There is no interaction among Carb, Protein and Fat
Ha: There is an interaction among Carb, Protein and Fat

Comment: Carb: Low (A1) and High (A2)
Protein: Low (B1) and High (B2)
Fat: Low (C1) and High (C2)

Thanks
8 treatments 

A1 B1 C1;
A1 B1 C2;
A1 B2 C1;
A1 B2 C2;
A1 B1 C1;
A2 B1 C2;
A2 B2 C1;
A2 B2 C2;

Comment: With those edits, +1; I think this question is now much more likely to get answers (or maybe additional requests for clarification) than puzzlement in response -- but I  think I'll leave this for others, since I think it's now right in the wheelhouse of some here. I've now deleted my half dozen comments, since the specific issues being raised seem to have been sorted.

Comment: First question: What is the dependent variable? You mentioned prostate cancer in the comment but I am not sure how it was recorded (as yes/no or concentration of PSA?) Second question: what is the reason of dichotomizing all the nutrients? Please realize that aggregating continuous to this extend can waste a lot of information. Third question: this is about the nutrition aspect... how did you decide high and low? Have you perform energy adjustment first?